# Purpose of if(cin)?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm here to ask for some help in understanding some concepts presented in accelerated c++.  Here is where I am having a problem.

```
vector<Student_info> students;  //Student_info is a structure we made
Student_info record;
string::size_type maxlen = 0;


// read and store all the records, and find the length of the longest name
while (read(cin, record)) { //Here is where I find hard to follow
maxlen = max(maxlen, record.name.size());
students.push_back(record);
}
```

Definition of read():

```
istream& read(istream& is, Student_info& s)
{
// read and store the student's name and midterm and final exam grades
is >> s.name >> s.midterm >> s.final;
read_hw(is, s.homework); // read and store all the student's homework grades
return is;
}
```

definition of read_hw():

```
// read homework grades from an input stream into a vector<double>
istream& read_hw(istream& in, vector<double>& hw)
{
if (in) {
// get rid of previous contents
hw.clear() ;
// read homework grades
double x;
while (in >> x)
hw.push_back(x);
// clear the stream so that input will work for the next student
in.clear();
}
return in;
}
```

The way I understand it so far is that when we call: `while (read(cin,record))` we ask for a string: `record.name`, and two `double` values: `record.midterm` and `record.final`.  After our user has inputted that data, we will enter our `read_hw()` function where we will clear any previous elements that may have been in our vector.  Then we input and record a a stream of values into a vector of homework grades called `record.homework`.  I think I am understanding that much.  If not, please let me know.

I don't understand how our function knows when to return in, and therefore return back to our first `while` loop.  EDIT: Ah, the user has to make and end-of-file notification twice to end the program.   So I suppose I answered my own question... But would someone be able to  explain the purpose of  `if(in)` in our `read_hw()` function, that would be very helpful. It would be `if(cin)`, so does that wait for our user to input data? Or is `if(cin)` automatically true? (why?)

Comment: Now I get it.  Thanks for the help guys.  I sort of understood the basic way the function worked. But now I see that the if(cin) expression, specifically, aside from end-of-file, is what may determine if we continue to run our while loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No `if(cin)` doesn't wait - it checks for errors. Only the operator >> waits for input. In this case `while(in >> x)` does the reading and waiting. The reasons it is inside a while loop condition is because after `in >> x` finishes it returns a reference to in, which is implicitly converted to a bool, which is used to signal an error like `if(cin)`.

In both cases, cin will be true if there has been no error, and false if there has been an error.

[This](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/) gives a better idea of what is going on, but might be not be to welcoming. Basically whenever an istream is treated like a bool, it will be true is there was no error, and false if there has been an error.

Basically, the conversion of an istream (call it foo) to bool is always !foo.fail(). So it is the opposite of fail(). This means there are two ways it can be true (straight from the table [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail/):

1. Logical error on i/o operation (reading the wrong type, etc)
2. Read/writing error on i/o operation (the unpredictable stuff)

So end of file isn't covered at all. That has to be checked with eof() or similar.

If an istream works out as false, you can distinguish between 1 and 2 using bad(). If bad is true it was case 2, if bad() is false, it will be case 1. (There are other ways as well, look at rdstate())

Comment: OK I think I see the use of if(cin) now with that explanation. Though I don't necessarily understand how it works (the link wasn't much help :P). I guess that is ok for now. So if I wanted to make if(cin) false, I could do something like enter a string when it is expecting an integer for, say record.midterm, and then it will exit the while loops. Is that right?

Comment: @DavidJhoo yep - there's actually two ways it can be false (it actually returns !cin.fail()). The first way is a "logical i/o error", such as a string is read into an int, and the second way is "Read/writing error on i/o operation"