# What if ( !cin ) do

Tags: c++, cin

I have this code:

```
int temp;
cin >> temp;
if(!cin){
    cout << "a";
}else{
    cout << "b";
}
```

When I put a number, it printed `b`, but when I put a character, it printed `a`. What is happening here?

Comment: Consult a C++ reference to look at how the various `operators` are overloaded within `cin`. If you don't know what operator overloading is yet, then start by searching for a definition of that.

Comment: See [Purpose of if(cin)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20962046/597607)